# For Google Docs tables, how can we make an incomplete row have no bottom or top border (to show that it is incomplete on screen and on paper)?

Tags: google-docs, formatting

When we use Google Docs and create a table, sometimes a cell can span across two pages.  So for example, I can write a few lines (with Enter (line breaks)), and then, either on screen or on paper, the cell, even when it is not complete on that page, will have a bottom border, which is the default behavior of Google Docs.

So this can give a wrong impression on screen or on paper that the cell is actually complete, or an impression that on the next page, that cell is a totally complete, or independent cell.  The reader (or myself, months later when I read the document) will have to "guess" whether the cell content is complete or not.

(it could happen that: a person reading the document, thinking it is end of the row (end of the cell), and did not read further, and claim that the record "shows" what it is and claim to the other person that "computers don't lie". For example, if that last part is "customer called in, and arrange to make the payment in Sept, and we agreed". The company representative reading the row may miss this completely and think the row has ended, and therefore determined that the customer is delinquent and send him to the collection agency.)

Is there a way to make the bottom border not show (and on the next page, the top border not show) when the cell spans across two pages?

Alternatively, instead of no border, it can be a dotted line border or a light grey border too, if there are ways to do it?